# Split a Hex String without spaces and flip it

Tags: java, android, string, split

I need to split a string like this:

```
String= 0C46BA09
```

I know booth the StringTokenizer and the String.split() methods, and I have used them to split strings with spaces.

But in this case I haven't got spaces to set as condition, so... How could I split this string to get each char one by one?

**EDITED**

The real purpouse of this is to reverse this HEX String, so being this `0C46BA09` to get this `09BA460C`.

So, what I want to know if there is an easy way to do it, or the split() method is the only way to get it.

**EDITED 2**

New link with this last question:

[Flip a Hex String](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18830470/flip-a-hex-string)

Comment: Is the real 'real' purpose to operate on numeric quantities, but you're going via strings for convenience?

Comment: I need to operate first with int values, then I convert them into Hex, and for this I use strings

Comment: but what do you need at the end of it all; an int?

Comment: @masmic_87 Your new requirement is very interesting but probably best asked in a new question with clear description of the requirements for the numeric values

Comment: A String in hex format

Comment: @Reimeus your right, I haven't done it the best way. Do you think that I should write a new question with it?

Comment: Yes, a new question would be clearer for everyone I think

Comment: @masmic_87, I attach a purely numeric answer (will be much faster than going in and out of strings); inspired from endianness conversion

Comment: New question's link: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18830470/flip-a-hex-string

Answer (score 10):

You could do

```
char[] charArray = "0C46BA09".toCharArray();
```

Comment: Let suppose I'm doing this to get out of the string the chars `46BA`. Each will be in `charArray[x]`. Then I want to add these 4 again in other string. But I'm getting a conversion error. So I think I would have to add them in one char and reverse the conversion from char to string. The real porpouse of what I'm doing with this string `0C46BA09`, is change the order to this `09BA460C` being this string an hex string, so maybe there is a easiest way to do it.

Comment: @Tarsem That wont work `StringBuilder` will reverse all the characters rather than pairs of characters

Comment: Almost there @Tarsem but maybe I forgot to comment that is an Hex String so this conversion doesn't make what I'm looking for

Comment: So, there is no way to do this in one more easy way? I'm not asking this because I'm lazy xD. Just want to learn to do the things right

Comment: New question's link: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18830470/flip-a-hex-string

Answer (score 5):

Using for each  and  `toCharArray()`  method on String

```
for (Character c : s.toCharArray()) {
        System.out.println(c);
 }
```

O/P:

```
0
C
4
6
B
A
0
9
```

Update:

```
String s = "2B00FFEC";
StringBuilder  result = new StringBuilder();
for (int i = 0; i <=s.length()-2; i=i+2) {
    result.append(new StringBuilder(s.substring(i,i+2)).reverse());
 }
System.out.println(result.reverse().toString());   //op :ECFF002B
```

Comment: @Bathsheba yes.added the output too.

Comment: are you sure it's guaranteed by a standard? You need to earn that +1 I'm about to give you...

Comment: @Bathsheba Indeed :).what do you mean by `guaranteed by a standard`??A for loop ?

Comment: @Suresh Atta; I've been led to believe that the element order of a short form for loop should be regarded as arbitrary. So I don't see, on first examination, how you can guarantee the order.

Comment: @Bathsheba - the for(.. : ...) constuct uses the iterable nature of the right-side structure (in this case, a char[] array). It is guaranteed to run in sequence

Comment: @Bathsheba - http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-14.html#jls-14.14.2 - it's right, whether it looks precarious to you or not is not the point. The Language specification is the reference, and Suresh is right.

Comment: @Bathsheba, @sᴜʀᴇsʜ ᴀᴛᴛᴀ and @rolfl, sorry if I interrupt your discussion. I have ansewered @Reimeus's answer too. Booth this and te answer above I think are usefull for me, but I'm using the first above. Otherwise, the real purpose of what I'm doing is to change the order of the Hex String `0C46BA09` to this `09BA460C` and maybe there is a easiest way to achieve this.

Comment: can you please check my update.I added some possibility of resolving your issue.Hope that helps.

Answer (score 2):

```
String s = "0C46BA09";
s.split("");
```

this should do the work. The result will be `{ "", "0", "C", "4", "6", "B", "A", "0", "9", "" }`

Answer (score 2):

A purely numeric answer (inspired from idioms to convert endianness); saves going to and from strings

`n` is an `int`:

```
int m = ((n>>24)&0xff) |       // byte 3 to byte 0
        ((n<<8)&0xff0000) |    // byte 1 to byte 2
        ((n>>8)&0xff00) |      // byte 2 to byte 1
        ((n<<24)&0xff000000);  // byte 0 to byte 3
```

If you really need the hex,

```
Integer.toHexString(m);
```

Comment: +1 nice & correct - this should do for the `OP`'s [new question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18830470/flip-a-hex-string)

Comment: New question's link: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18830470/flip-a-hex-string

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you use

```
public String substring (int start, int end)
```

method then?

```
YOURSTRING= YOURSTRING.substring(4,8) + YOURSTRING.substring(0,4);
```

Answer (score 0):

If your aim is to reverse order of a hex string, probably this block of code will help.

```
String s = "0C46BA09";

long b = Long.parseLong(s, 16);
long l;
l += ((byte)b >> 0) << 24;
l += ((byte)b >> 8) << 16;
l += ((byte)b >> 16) << 8;
l += ((byte)b >> 24) << 0;

System.out.println(Long.toHexString(l));
```