# Flip a Hex String

Tags: java, android, string, flip

Acording to a other question made here [Split a Hex String without spaces and flip it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18829256/split-a-hex-string-without-spaces-and-flip-it), I write this new question more clearly here.

I have an Hex String like this:

```
Hex_string = 2B00FFEC
```

What I need is to change the order of the Hex String to start from the latest characters, so this would be like this:

```
Fliped_hex_string = ECFF002B
```

In the other question I asked a way to achieve this using the .split() method. But there should be another way to get this in a better way.

Comment: What does the Hex_string represent; a long (i.e. 64 bit)?

Comment: Always an even number of characters?

Comment: Just try that: `Fliped_hex_string = new StringBuilder(Hex_string).reverse().toString();`

Comment: Always an even number of characters?

Comment: @YoannHercouet No, that won't work.

Comment: Yes @Bathsheba, it's always 8 char long, or in other way, 4 byte long

Comment: @masmic_87l that is at odds with your question example.

Comment: @Bathsheba your right! I haven't realized! Is changed now

Comment: @masmic_87, so I've reattached what I think is the best way of doing this. Will be at least one order of magnitude quicker than going in and out of strings.

Comment: No it's not a 'simple string'. If it were, the flipped result you would want would be CEFF00B2, which is not what you put as the required result.

Comment: Yes previously it's not.Now OP edited the post.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**OP constrains the character length to exactly 8 characters in comments**.

A purely numeric answer (inspired from idioms to convert endianness); saves going to and from strings

`n` is an `int`:

```
int m = ((n>>24)&0xff) |       // byte 3 to byte 0
        ((n<<8)&0xff0000) |    // byte 1 to byte 2
        ((n>>8)&0xff00) |      // byte 2 to byte 1
        ((n<<24)&0xff000000);  // byte 0 to byte 3
```

If you need to convert this to hexadecimal, use

```
String s = Integer.toHexString(m);
```

and if you need to set `n` from hexadecimal, use

```
int n = (int)Long.parseLong(hex_string, 16);
```

where `hex_string` is your initial string. You need to go via the `Long` parser to allow for negatives.

Comment: Sorry for my ignorance @Bathsheba, I'm a bit newbie in android, but I don't know how to use this. Where I use my string `Hex_string`?

Comment: @maxmic_87, I now attach the setting code at the end of the answer.

Answer (score 8):

As simple as you can is

```
    String s = "2B00FFEC";
    StringBuilder  result = new StringBuilder();
    for (int i = 0; i <=s.length()-2; i=i+2) {
        result.append(new StringBuilder(s.substring(i,i+2)).reverse());
     }
    System.out.println(result.reverse().toString());   //op :ECFF002B
```

Comment: nice one simple n short

Answer (score 5):

You could do something like:

```
String a = "456789AB";
char[] ca = a.toCharArray();
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(a.length());
for (int i = 0; i<a.length();i+=2)
{
  sb.insert(0, ca, i, 2);
}
```

This also extends to longer Strings if needed

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you should try something as simple as this:

```
public static String flip(final String hex){
    final StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder(hex.length());
    for(int i = hex.length(); i > 1; i-=2)
        builder.append(hex.substring(i-2, i));
    return builder.toString();
}

public static void main(String args[]){
    System.out.println(flip("2B00FFEC"));
}
```

The output is: `ECFF002B`

Next time you ask a question, perhaps you should show us some code you've written used in order to solve your problem (and then ask us why your code doesn't work, not your problem). You will not learn *anything* from us just providing answers without you knowing how they work.

Answer (score 0):

This method seems to do what you want

```
String changeHexOrder(String s) {
    char[] arr = s.toCharArray();
    char tmp;
    //change positions of [i, i + 1 , , , , , ,length - i - 2, length - i - 1]
    for (int i = 0; i < arr.length / 2; i += 2) {
        tmp = arr[i];
        arr[i] = arr[arr.length-i-2];
        arr[arr.length-i-2] = tmp;

        tmp = arr[i+1];
        arr[i+1] = arr[arr.length-i-1];
        arr[arr.length-i-1] = tmp;
    }
    return new String(arr);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me

```
    StringBuilder lsbToMsb=new StringBuilder();

    for(int i=input.length();i>0;i-=2)
    {
        lsbMsb.append(lsbToMsb.substring(i-2,i));
    }


    String lsbMsb=lsbMsb.toString();
```